# How can I get my 2005 kia amanti out of park and into neutral. The battery is dead

Tags: kia, amanti, shifter

My car is in park.   i want it in neutral.  battery is dead.  How can i force it into neutral?  Car is 2005 kia amanti.

Comment: Most vehicles have a manual unlock, where you use the ign key and poke it a hole near the shifter.

Comment: Grab your owners' manual and find the section that tells you how to manually unlock the shifter.

Comment: Why not recharge or replace the battery?

Comment: Push the brakes at the same time